# uWSGI doesn't recognize --http nor --wsgi-file options

Tags: python, linux, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup a webserver with `nginx`, `uwsgi` and `django`.
`nginx` works and it serves the files in `/srv` just like I intended to. However I can't get `uwsgi` to work properly. My biggest problem is that I used [this tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) and they don't seem to use the version of `uwsgi` that I use.

At one point they call `uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py`, but my `uwsgi` has neither the `--http` long option, nor `--wsgi-file` long option. `uwsgi --version` prints `2.0.7-debian`.

What can I call instead of `--wsgi-file`?

UPDATE:

This works fine, i.e. I can see my website on localhost on port 8000:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

However this does not:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module django_test.wsgi
```

It will complain, that it doesn't know the long option `--http` as well as the long option `--module`. It all seems to boil down to uwsgi, which on my machine just doesn't behave as it does everywhere else.

Comment: It's not really the answer to your problem but I would personally recommend gunicorn instead of uwsgi. The 1200 (yes, I counted) uwsgi commandline parameters are just a mess

Comment: Already got it running with `gunicorn`, wow that was incredibly fast. Thanks for your recommendation! However if someone knows an answer to this mystery, I'd still like to hear it.

Comment: @Wolph uWSGI is totally different than gunicorn. uWSGI is not only an wsgi server, it can do lot more (psgi, php, cgi, routing, serving static files and so on, and so on). It also contains managing of running uWSGI instances, that's why it contains so much options. But when using as normal wsgi server, you will need small fraction of them.

Comment: @GwynBleidD: true, but if he's running Django than it's a regular Python install in which case Gunicorn is definitely an easier option that works quite well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI installed from debian packages doesn't have any built-in plugins, and for that parameters to work, you will need:

- http plugin for `--http` parameter
- python plugin for `--module` (or any wsgi related) parameter

You can fix this in 2 ways: installing all required plugins (`uwsgi-plugins-all` package will install all available plugins on debian) and loading them explicitly (`--plugin http` and `--plugin python`) or by replacing uWSGI by fully featured one (`sudo pip install uwsgi` will do that). Second solution will tie your uWSGI up to certain python version, for first one, you can just load another python plugin (`python3` for example).

Comment: I had several instances of `uwsgi` installed. The executable `uwsgi_python3` did the trick for me.